# Awesomium WebCore isInitialised?

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

I'm initialising the WebCore in a WPF application using

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var config = new WebCore.Config { enablePlugins = true, saveCacheAndCookies = false };
        WebCore.Initialize(config);
    }
```

I am using OnStartup on `App.xaml.cs`.

I then later call a function to call up a web page,

```
  webViewControl1.LoadURL(url)
```

The application works in Windows 7 and the web page, but in Windows XP nothing loads.

I used to start up the configuration every time the WebBrowser page, using the code above, but then it seemed to load multiple instances of the WebCore and crash.

As a test, I added the code to init a WebCore object back to the web browser page and the Windows 7 version crashed.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: I have to ask, why aren't you using the built in `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: because it doesnt do what I need it to do, ie external links bring up a new window and also awesomium is more locked down.